# Prior/Posterior of the Proxy

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, vector-autoregression

I am trying to understand a sentence from Caldara and Herbst (2019), who develop a baysian proxy SVAR model. The paragraph is:

> "In case of weak identification, the prior plays an important role in
> inference. But **in our framework comparing  prior to posterior
> distributions, a standard diagnostic to detect identification issues,
> is trivial.** The reason is that, as  already shown by equation (12),
> when it comes to identification, the relevant prior distributions are
> those implied by  the model before observing M1:T but after observing
> Y1:T. Finally, lack of identification or weak identification, which
> manifests itself in flat or nearly flat likelihood profiles, could
> pose practical issues when sampling the posterior."

I am confused about what "trivial" means in this case. I am used to seeing plots of the prior vs posterior distributions in Bayesian papers, and it seems this is omitted here because such a plot would not be informative. Is this the correct understanding? I understand that this question is probably super difficult to answer even for people much more familiar with Baysian econometrics than I am. So in case it helps, here is a bride summary of the Baysian proxy SVAR:

The SVAR in compact form is: [image]

Take the reduced-form to be: [image]

where the structural and the reduced form are linked through:[image].

The proxy m_t is linked to the structural shock e_mp,t by:[image].

The likelihood (which is the equation (12) the paragraph above refers to) is given by:
[image]

where the paragraph posted above is footnote 6 of the last sentence.

I understand that this question is probably way to long and requires too much reading of the paper for an easy answer, but I would be very thankful for any help with understanding this.